# How to repeat an AnimationSet with sequentially added animations

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to make an animation in my `Activity`, to be repeated infinite times. I have already tried it in XML file with `repeatCount` and `repeatMode` attributes, but it doesn't work. The thing is that `myanimation.xml` file is constructed of a set of different animations.

My XML file for that animation

```
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator"
>



<translate


    android:startOffset="1000"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromXDelta="10"
    android:fromYDelta="10"
    android:toXDelta="50"
    android:toYDelta="-200"
    android:duration="1800"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator"

    />



<translate

    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:startOffset="2000"
    android:fromYDelta="10"
    android:fromXDelta="10"
    android:toXDelta="100"
    android:toYDelta="270"
    android:duration="1800"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator" />

<translate

    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:startOffset="3000"
    android:fromYDelta="10"
    android:fromXDelta="10"
    android:toXDelta="130"
    android:toYDelta="-270"
    android:duration="1800"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator"
    />

<translate

    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:startOffset="4000"
    android:fromYDelta="10"
    android:fromXDelta="10"
    android:toXDelta="140"
    android:toYDelta="270"
    android:duration="1800"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator"
    />

<translate

    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:startOffset="5000"
    android:fromYDelta="10"
    android:fromXDelta="10"
    android:toXDelta="90"
    android:toYDelta="-270"
    android:duration="1800"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator"
    />
```

And in `onCreate()` I have animation tied to a `ImageView` object.

```
    ImageView ball = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.animationBall);
    final Animation myAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,   R.anim.ball_animation);
    ball.startAnimation(myAnimation);
```

The animation works fine, the only thing is that it doesn't want to repeat itself, even if I set the `setRepeatMode()` or `setRepeatCount()` methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For what its worth, `setRepeatMode()` and `setRepeatCount()` have to be set on the `Animation` objects, and not on the `AnimationSet` object. That's potentially a mistake you may have made.

So either call those methods on the `Animation` objects or add those attributes to the XML of the `translate` schema.

Another approach is to set an endlessly repeating animation as follows:

```
mAnimationSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
        mAnimationSet.start();
    }

});
mAnimationSet.start();
```

Comment: thanks in the third approach worked for, all I needed to do, was to implement AnimationListener

Comment: It's work. But I think Google should add RepeatCount method to AnimatorSet

Comment: it seems you cannot cancel the animation this way.  it repeats forever.

Comment: @j2emanue: I said as much ... :) But I've also mentioned another way.

Comment: To address this problem, we may [vote on Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36929638) and demand that AnimatorSet supports `repeatMode` and `repeatCount` XML attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Y.S answer seems ok but the animation kept  going even though i wanted it cancelled at some point. so i did this:

```
 animations.playSequentially(
                objectAnimator1,objectAnimator2)



animations.addListener(object: Animator.AnimatorListener{
       var isCancelled = false
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {
        }

        override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {
            isCancelled = true
        }

        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {
        }

        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
           if(isCancelled.not()) animations.start()
        }

    })
    animations.start()
```

UPDATE: FOUND OUT ktx has a few [extension functions](https://gist.github.com/kpob/c0d303dadb9ea3ad4afdc9f37ac390a8): we can remove the boilerplate overloads and use this:

```
inline fun Animator.addListener(
    crossinline onEnd: (animator: Animator) -> Unit = {},
    crossinline onStart: (animator: Animator) -> Unit = {},
    crossinline onCancel: (animator: Animator) -> Unit = {},
    crossinline onRepeat: (animator: Animator) -> Unit = {})
```

so that means you can just do something like this if you just wanted the onEnd called:

```
 animations.addListener(onEnd = {animations.start() //loop forever })
```

and instead of cancel just use animations.pause and animations.resume.