# How to repeat an android xml animation

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, animation

I try to animate a textview in a fragment to fly in - stay there for some seconds  - fly out - repeat. The animation works, but I don't get it to repeat it. When the animation is over, the AnimationListener fires the onAnimationEnd event. I tried it with `setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);`
and `setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART/Animation.REVERSE);`, but nothing seems to work.

Here you can see the text_slider_animation.xml file with the animation content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">

    <set
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fillEnabled="true"
        android:startOffset="500"
        android:duration="1000">
        <translate
            android:fromXDelta="-100%"
            android:toXDelta="0%" />
        <alpha
            android:fromAlpha="0.0"
            android:toAlpha="1.0" />
    </set>

    <set
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fillEnabled="true"
        android:startOffset="6000"
        android:duration="1000">
        <translate
            android:fromXDelta="0%"
            android:toXDelta="100%" />
        <alpha
            android:fromAlpha="1.0"
            android:toAlpha="0.0" />
    </set>
</set>
```

I tried to use this with following code:

```
AnimationSet mAnimation = (AnimationSet) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.text_slider_animation);
mAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
myTextView.startAnimation(mAnimation);
mAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Repeat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // TODO: Replace text in TextView
    }
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Finish", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Can somebody please help me why this is not working? Thank you in advance!

///////////////////////

Edit: I Corrected the lines mAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);

Comment: I saw this post, but unfortunately could not solve my problem with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question, you are setting *mode* as **count** and **count** as *mode*.

```
setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE); 
setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
// or setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
```

EDIT:

It seems that there's some confusion here. You are creating `AnimationSet` and not `Animation`. Unfortunately, `AnimationSet` does not seem to support repetition as well as `Animation`.

So you'd need to call `animationSet.start()` in `onAnimationEnd` callback. For further details, check this answer. [How to repeat an AnimationSet with sequentially added animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732557/how-to-repeat-an-animationset-with-sequentially-added-animations/30732716)

In `onAnimationEnd` calling `view.startAnimation(animationSet)` seems to work as well.

Comment: Oups, It seems i am already asleep ;)
Nevertheless, it does also not work with 
mAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART/Animation.REVERSE);

The onAnimationEnd does still fire

Comment: Any idea why it is still not working with the corrected upper two lines? onAnimationRepeat does still not fire. I tried many constellations with repeat mode and count

Comment: Did you use `Animation.RESTART` or `Animation.REVERSE`?

Comment: Both, did both not work. Happens nothing. onAnimationEnd is called and that was it.

Comment: Both, together?

Comment: No, seperate. Compiled - tried on emulator and then tried the other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196142/discussion-between-chris2011931-and-froyo).

Answer (score 0):

In XML, add:

```
android:repeatMode="restart"
```

Comment: I tried this and it does still fire the "end" event and does not repeat (added it in the root-set-tag).

Comment: how many times you want to repeat? because every time animation completed, onAnimationEnd called

Comment: I want to repeat still the fragment is going to be destroyed. I get, that the onAnimationEnd sould be called every time, but the onAnimationRepeat does never fire.